# Join to table and if no match join to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

I need to join to a table and if no matches join to another table.

Main Table - A

| Id | Code | DataId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | testa | 123 |
| 2 | testb | 456 |

Table - B

| Idb | Code | DataId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | testa | 123 |

Table - C

| Idb | Code | DataId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | testb | 456 |

In my sample data above I would need result set to be:

| Id | Code | DataId | Idb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | testa | 123 | 22 |
| 2 | testb | 456 | 33 |

I've tried left joining Table A to Table B.  This gives me a null DataId for the 2nd record - understandably.  I could do another left join to Table C.  Is that the right approach?  Or is joining to a table and if no matches join to another table viable?

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Can table b and table c both contain the same `code`? Is `code` unique? If not what do you expect?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is a match for you? Which columns must be put in the on clause of your join? Code only or DataId only or both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd left join on both tables and `coalesce` the `idb` columns:

```sql
SELECT    a.*, COALESCE(b.idb, c.idb)
FROM      a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.code = b.code
LEFT JOIN c ON a.code = c.code
```

Comment: ON clause should exclude other dim table